# ingress's service port and service's port is not same. But it works. why...?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: miro-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: miro.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: miro-service
              port:
                number: 9000
          path: /api
          pathType: Prefix
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: miro-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: miro-pod
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: miro-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: miro-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: miro-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: ${address}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: ${name}
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
```

ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.service.port is 9000
service.spec.ports[0].port is 8000

Two port number is different but it works. I don't know why it works...

I also try some examples.

ingress's service port: 8000
service port: 3000
service targetPort: 9000
pod containerPort: 9000
=> It doesn't work

ingress's service port: 9000
service port: 3000
service targetPort: 9000
pod containerPort: 9000
=> It works